# Batch Script - Else is not Working properly

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

```
@echo on

::findstr /C:"Not connected" /C:"Invalid command" /C:"530 Login incorrect" D:\PATH1\Log_output1.txt

findstr /C:"Not connected" /C:"Invalid command" /C:"530 Login incorrect" D:\PATH1\Log_output2.txt

set /a _retVal=%errorlevel%

if %_retVal%==0 (
    goto Error
) else if %_retVal%==1 (
    goto NoError
) else (
    echo Do Nothing!
)
rem *********************************

:NoError
echo Error is not present

:Error
echo Error is present
```

**Command Line Output:**
**Case 1 - This is working fine. In `Log_output1.txt` file, errors are present.**

> ```
> D:\PATH1\scripts\ppt>test1.bat
>
> D:\PATH1\scripts\ppt>findstr /C:"Not connected" /C:"Invalid command" /C:"530 Login incorrect" D:\PATH1\Log_output1.txt
> Invalid command.
> Invalid command.
> Not connected.
> Not connected.
> Not connected.
> Not connected.
>
> D:\PATH1\scripts\ppt>set /a _retVal=0
>
> D:\PATH1\scripts\ppt>if 0 == 0 (goto Error )  else if 0 == 1 (goto NoError )  else (echo Do Nothing! )
>
> D:\PATH1\scripts\ppt>echo Error is present
>
> Error is present
>
> D:\PATH1\scripts\ppt>
> ```

**Case 2 - This is not WORKING. where `Log_output2.txt` file doesn't contain any error**
** Both if and else conditions are getting printed**

> ```
> D:\PATH1\scripts\ppt>test1.bat
>
> D:\PATH1\scripts\ppt>findstr /C:"Not connected" /C:"Invalid command" /C:"530 Login incorrect" D:\PATH1\Log_output2.txt
>
> D:\PATH1\scripts\ppt>set /a _retVal=1
>
> D:\PATH1\scripts\ppt>if 1 == 0 (goto Error )  else if 1 == 1 (goto NoError )  else (echo Do Nothing! )
>
> D:\PATH1\scripts\ppt>echo Error is not present
>
> Error is not present
>
> D:\PATH1\scripts\ppt>echo Error is present
>
> Error is present
>
> D:\PATH1\scripts\ppt>
> ```

Comment: what other behavior would you expect when you have failed to code in a script break to prevent overflow between `:noerror` and `:error`?

Comment: Code flows line by line, if you don't tell it not to go into `:Error` after it's finished in `:NoError`, then it will go there! Of course you could just do it in one line with conditional execution instead of using the error level: `@%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /I /C:"Not connected" /C:"Invalid command" /C:"530 Login incorrect" "D:\PATH1\Log_output#.txt" >NUL 2>&1 && (Echo Error is present) || (Echo Error is not present)`. _(just change the `#` to the appropriate number)_

Comment: Hi @Compo Will you please explain this?
And I don't want to go to the end of this script if any of the label is called. I have some more commands to run after executing the labels.

Comment: @saroj, I'm not a personal consultant, and I'm not explaining something I haven't said. I have not told you to 'go to the end of this script' and my code doesn't either. You simply need to put the code from below your `:Error` label, into the first pair of parentheses, and that form your `:NoError` label into the second pair of parentheses, please see my answer to see it split over multiple lines for readability.

Answer (score 0):

To do it as you had, you need to instruct your code not to flow into the next label, if you don't want it to do so.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /I ^
 /C:"Not connected" ^
 /C:"Invalid command" ^
 /C:"530 Login incorrect" ^
 "D:\PATH1\Log_output#.txt" >NUL 2>&1

If %ErrorLevel% Equ 0 GoTo :Error
Echo Error is not present
Rem Your other commands if no error match was found go here.
GoTo Continue

:Error
Echo Error is present
Rem Your other commands if an error match was found go here.

:Continue
Rem Any other commands to run in both scenarios below here.
```

Although you could possibly use `Call` instead of `GoTo`

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /I ^
 /C:"Not connected" ^
 /C:"Invalid command" ^
 /C:"530 Login incorrect" ^
 "D:\PATH1\Log_output#.txt" >NUL 2>&1

If %ErrorLevel% Equ 0 (
    Call :Error
) Else If %ErrorLevel% Equ 1 Call :NoError

Rem Any other commands to run in both scenarios below here.

Rem Any other commands to run in both scenarios above here.
GoTo :EOF

:Error
Echo Error is present
Rem Your other commands if an error match was found go here.
Exit /B

:NoError
Echo Error is not present
Rem Your other commands if no error match was found go here.
Exit /B
```

However you could just parenthesise your command blocks, using the errorlevel:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /I ^
 /C:"Not connected" ^
 /C:"Invalid command" ^
 /C:"530 Login incorrect" ^
 "D:\PATH1\Log_output#.txt" >NUL 2>&1

If %ErrorLevel% Equ 1 (
    Echo Error is not present
    Rem Your other commands if no error match was found go here.
) Else (
    Echo Error is present
    Rem Your other commands if an error match was found go here.
)
Rem Any other commands to run in both scenarios below here.
```

Or using conditional execution:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /I ^
 /C:"Not connected" ^
 /C:"Invalid command" ^
 /C:"530 Login incorrect" ^
 "D:\PATH1\Log_output#.txt" >NUL 2>&1 && (
    Echo Error is present
    Rem Your other commands if an error match was found go here.
) || (
    Echo Error is not present
    Rem Your other commands if no error match was found go here.
)
Rem Any other commands to run in both scenarios below here.
```